# Need a better way to append JAVA_HOME to PATH in csh

Tags: linux, csh

I need to define JAVA_HOME and then include $JAVA_HOME/bin in the $PATH. Here is how I am doing it -

```
setenv JAVA_HOME "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64"
setenv PATH $PATH":"$JAVA_HOME"/bin"
```

I think including the colons and the forward slash and bin in quotes looks ugly and certainly not elegant. Is there a better way to achieve the task above? Thanks in advance.

I am using c-shell.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much you can do to clean this up, most of what you speak of would be considered 'features' by shell programmers ;-)

But recall that in any shell, the dbl-quoting of text allows any environment variables to be expanded to the value. So you can reduces your PATH assignment to

```
 setenv PATH "$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

If you're certain your original PATH value does not (and more importantly **will not**) have any spaces in it, you could reduce it even further by removing the surrounding dbl-quotes.

I hope this helps.